# how to create batch code to filter the content of all txt file and add a sentence based on filtered text

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm not familiar with batch, but I do know how to copy paste and move text file to another folder... only things is now I have to add text based on certain key word in all the txt file before copy out...

it goes like this, I have a folder auto generate txt file everyday.
I did make a batch to copy them to another folder everyday at a certain time.

But, before doing that.. I have to edit the content of text file whichever contain A123 on 2nd row will need to add a sentence Dept. A on the last row or end of the text.. same goes if contain B123 then add a different last sentence to the text.

So what I have in mind is to filter all txt file then add the text that match the filtering.

So, can this be done?

I tried as below batch code but return error = The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

```
@echo off
findstr /c:"^[^ ][^ ]*A123" (*.txt) do type Dept A >> (*.txt)
exit /b
```

what do I need to add or change?

Comment: Why not use a language other than batch?

Comment: which one is more easy?? I have no knowledge on other language

Comment: @Alan.C Can you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1727546/edit) your question and add by example the input and output excpected, just for one file

Answer (score 0):

***Remark :*** This is just for testing with only one file with drag and drop.

If we had for example the input file like this one :

---

> ```
> Hello
> Other Stuff here A123
> Line 3....
> Line 4.....
> Line 5......
> Line 6.......
> ```

---

With this batch code you can get as output like this one :

---

> ```
> Hello
> Other Stuff here A123
> Line 3....
> Line 4.....
> Line 5......
> Line 6.......
> Dept. A
> ```

---

You should Drag and Drop a file for testing on this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Title Read an InputFile line by line and match condition in order to add something at the end of file
Set "OutputFile=%~dp0OutputFile.txt"
If Exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%"
Set "InputFile=%1"
If Not Defined InputFile ( echo(You should Drag and Drop a file on this batch file "%~nx0" ... & Timeout /T 5 /Nobreak>nul & Exit /B)
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!InputFile!" (
    @for /f %%i in ('type "!InputFile!"^|find /c /v ""') do @for /l %%j in (1 1 %%i) do (
        Set "line=" & set /p "line="
        echo(!line! | find /I "A123" && Set "Word2Insert=Dept. A" && echo(!line!>>"!OutputFile!"
        ) || (
            echo(!line!>>"!OutputFile!"
        )
    )
)
echo(!Word2Insert!>>"!OutputFile!"
Start "" /MAX "!OutputFile!"
```